# What is the name of $(ωt+\varphi)$ in sine wave?

Tags: waves, terminology

For a sine wave $x=A\sin(ωt+\varphi)$,

- $A$ is the amplitude
- $\omega$ is the frequency
- $\varphi$ is the phase

What is $(ωt+\varphi)$ called? "Angle"? I can't find any source call that part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\omega t + \varphi$ is called the *phase*. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_(waves)) for the details.

The symbol $\varphi$ is known variously as the *phase shift*, *phase offset* or *phase constant*.

Comment: Wikipedia is not an authority on the use is scientific or technical terminology. In common speech, $\varphi$ is called both the "phase" and the "phase offset", and probably other things, all determined by *context*. It is misleading to claim that there's a universal and consistent use of terms.

Answer (score 4):

As with functions in general, the quantity inside $\sin$ here is called an argument.